# .bind() and .unbind() doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bind, unbind

I have two links that if a user click one,the article related to the link will be shown in an animation.if a user clicks another link after he/she clicked the first and before the previous animation is done,their animations will be conflicted.I want to use `.bind()` and `.unbind()` functions to prevent user from clicking a link while other link's event is working.but when I unbind an event,it won't bind to the element after animation.

**JS** Code:

```
$("a[href='#about-enamel']").click(function () {
        $("a[href!='#about-enamel']").unbind("click");
        if ($("article[id='about-enamel']").attr('class') === 'visible') {
            $("a[href!='#about-enamel']").bind("click");
            return 0;
        }
        else if ($("article[class='visible']").length) {
            $("article[class='visible']").hide('drop', { easing: 'easeOutBack', direction: 'down' }, 500, function () {
                $(this).attr('class', 'hidden');
                $("article[id='about-enamel']").show('drop', { easing: 'easeInBack', direction: 'up' }, 500, function () {
                    $(this).attr('class', 'visible');
                    $("a[href!='#about-enamel']").bind("click");
                });
            });
        }
        else {
            $("article[id='about-enamel']").show('drop', { easing: 'easeInBack', direction: 'up' }, 500, function () {
                $(this).attr('class', 'visible');
                $("a[href!='#about-enamel']").bind("click");
            });
        }
    });
    $("a[href='#order']").click(function () {
        $("a[href!='#order']").unbind("click");
        if ($("article[id='order']").attr('class') === 'visible') {
            $("a[href!='#order']").bind("click");
            return 0;
        }
        else if ($("article[class='visible']").length) {
            $("article[class='visible']").hide('drop', { easing: 'easeOutBack', direction: 'down' }, 500, function () {
                $(this).attr('class', 'hidden');
                $("article[id='order']").show('drop', { easing: 'easeInBack', direction: 'up' }, 500, function () {
                    $(this).attr('class', 'visible');
                    $("a[href!='#order']").bind("click");
                });
            });
        }
        else {

            $("article[id='order']").show('drop', { easing: 'easeInBack', direction: 'up' }, 500, function () {
                $(this).attr('class', 'visible');
                $("a[href!='#order']").bind("click");
            });
        }
    });
```

If this problem has other solutions,please inform me.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood how `bind` and `unbind` work. You bind an event - e.g. `$("a[href='#about-enamel']").click(function () {});` - and then immediately unbind it - `$("a[href!='#about-enamel']").unbind("click");`. Consider using `stop()` (http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to clear the animation queue when clicking a link, and then immediately hide any open `article` elements, before opening another. If you can post up the HTML, then more comprehensive answers may be more forthcoming.

Comment: @james246 I've not unbidden the event right after creating it.I am saying that when an $("a[href='#about-enamel']") click event is triggered,any a element that does not have #about-enamel href(the != symbol) should be unbidden from the click event.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't see the `!`· I do still believe that you can achieve your aim in a simpler way though- with a single click event which opens an article using an animation, but cancels any other animations that are in progress.

Comment: so if you have an idea, please share with me.

Comment: btw, you should use `.on()` and `.off()` rather than bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a basic example I've put together illustrating how to use `stop()` to kill any in-progress animations, so you can start another without them conflicting.

http://jsfiddle.net/zFAY9/3/